# C# in Visual Studio, combobox dropdown disappears when scrollbar clicked - Bug?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have several System.Windows.Forms.Combobox whose dropdowns close when I click on the scrollbar. I can use the arrow to scroll to the bottom, then it allows me to click and drag the scrollbar. The dropdown also disappears sometimes when I click between the bar and the arrows, although sometimes it doesn't. I've tried changing a lot of parameters but to no avail. Scrolling with the mouse wheel works perfectly. This seems like a bug, has anyone come across it?

I have turned off all event handlers for the combobox and it still shows the same behaviour.

This is the Designer code for the combobox (cmbSubmit):

```
this.cmbSubmit.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
this.cmbSubmit.DropDownWidth = 620;
this.cmbSubmit.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.cmbSubmit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 30);
this.cmbSubmit.Name = "cmbSubmit";
this.cmbSubmit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(620, 33);
this.cmbSubmit.TabIndex = 0;
```

And the code where I add items to the combobox:

```
cmbSubmit.Items.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < 100/*numItems*/; i++)
{
    cmbSubmit.Items.Add("" + i);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you create a *brand new* project, add a combobox to a form, and use this code, can you reproduce the behavior? I'm too lazy to fire up a VM with Visual Studio at the moment, but I'm betting this is non-reproducible, considering how many times I've used comboboxen from WinForms without a problem.

Comment: as @CodyGray told - if you create a new project and add code that you just wrote - ComboBox will behave properly. Most likely it is not cmbSubmit it is something else in your project/class that interferes with cmbSubmit, that's why changing cmbSubmit properties does not help.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and sorry for such a late reply. The issue was that the combobox was in a panel that closed when you click outside it and the dropdown dropped outside the panel, meaning that the panel closed, taking the combobox with it, when you clicked on the part of the scrollbar that was not in the panel.